# Create a flags tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the past few months, we've quite a few Kolomogorov Complexity challenges asking us to output different flags. For this reason, (and as Fatalize suggested), I think we should create a tag especially for flags?

Does anyone agree or oppose to this?

Comment: Pretty sure Fatalize was kidding.

Comment: Regardless of whether he was kidding or not, I think generally more tags is better than fewer tags. It's also not a meta tag, so I don't really see why we shouldn't add it.

Comment: @AlexA. Still seems like a good idea ;)

Comment: Given the multiple meanings of flag (look what comes up [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=flag+is%3Aquestion)), the tag wiki will need to clarify which flags we mean. We should also work out what flag questions we want e.g. should [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28784/the-star-spangled-code-challenge?s=18|0.1842) question be included?

Comment: @Sp3000 I guess any challenge that involves outputting a country's flag. Of course excluding any other meaning

Comment: I think we should create a more general tag, for all images that have similar characteristics to a flag.

Comment: Although I voted in favor of such tag, maybe “flag” is not the best name as it sounds like something suitable for [Draw the South Korean flag](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40052/draw-the-south-korean-flag) and [Let's draw the flag of Nepal](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/lets-draw-the-flag-of-nepal) too.

Comment: As a sidenote: I *was* kidding

Answer (score 13):

## Yes, we should create a flag tag

It's better to have more tags than fewer tags. It also groups like challenges together making it easier to identify duplicates.

Comment: -1 from me (can't vote)

Comment: Sure, it'll make it easier to identify duplicate challenges, but I don't see how any "make this flag" challenge could be fundamentally distinct from any other.

Comment: I could imagine someone wanting to search for flag-printing challenges specifically.

Comment: I think flags are not exactly the same category as other [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenges, for example a periodic table related one. For example some flags can be generated relatively well by `///`, while it has no chance to solve a periodic table problem. So a flag for this category would not be completely pointless.

Comment: @AlexA. that argument is an argument to close them as duplicates.  If they aren't duplicates, then they are super related and therefore tag worthy.

Answer (score 12):

## No, we should not create a flag tag

It's sufficient to tag challenges related to flags as [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art), [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (if applicable), and [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity). The context of a flag will be apparent from the title.

All challenges relating to flags will be essentially the same challenge but with a different pattern to mimic.

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Comment: I *somewhat* agree. I wouldn't be a fan of having a bunch of flag questions (as they're all very similar), but if they *are* going to be there, you might as well tag them up for searchability. If there are only two or three, then it's probably not needed.

Comment: There's 3+1 output-this-ASCII-art-flag (the +1 is the [semaphore](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/flag-semaphore-encoder?s=3|3.3152) question, which takes input), 2+1 output-this-image-flag (the +1 is the [maritime](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47423/ics-maritime-flag-alphabet?s=6|3.0432) question, which takes input) and 1 flag-related question (namely [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28784/the-star-spangled-code-challenge?s=18|0.1842)). Not sure if I've missed any.

Comment: +1, there is zero reason why anyone would want to search for only questions about printing flags and such a tag would hence just be noise.

Comment: People aren't rational.  I could absolutely see somebody enjoying a flag challenge, and saying "I want to do more flags", even though they really aren't that different from any other [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge